# prove $\phi$ is linear

Tags: complex-analysis

If $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset  of $C$, and
$\phi :\Omega\to\Omega$ be a holomorphic function satisfied $f(z_0)=z_0,f'(z_0)=1$ then prove that $\phi$ is linear.

The hint told me to let $z_0=0$, and $\phi(z)=z+Cz^n+O(z^{n+1})$, 
consider $\phi_k=\phi\circ\phi\circ...\circ\phi$ (k times),
then prove $\phi_k(z)=z+kCz^n+O(z^{n+1})$, use Cauchy's inequality 
and let $k\to\infty$ to get $C=0$.

I don't know how to prove 
$\phi_k(z)=z+kCz^n+O(z^{n+1})$ 
and here is where i have trouble:
assume that in $B(0,r_1)$ we have power series expansion of $\phi$:
$\phi(z)=z+Cz^n+O(z^{n+1})$ to make sure we have composite $\phi(\phi)$, we need to restrict $z$ in $D=\{z\in B(0,r_1):\phi(z)\in B(0,r_1)\}$ and assume the maximal disc of $\phi(\phi)$ that has a power series expansion in $D$ is $B(0,r_2)$, then only in this disc we can have $\phi_2=z+2Cz^n+O(z^{n+1})$, next consider $\phi_3$ and so on.

Now we have a series of disc $B_k=B(0,r_k)$ that only in $B_k$ we have the power series expansion $\phi_k(z)=z+kCz^n+O(z^{n+1})$, so what if $r_n$ tend to zero?

We can't let $k\to \infty$.

Comment: It is probably simpler to apply the Schwarz lemma if you can.

Comment: @lhf i think to use schwarz lemma we need to find a disc.$D$ contained in $\Omega$ centered at zero and $\phi(D)$ contained in D, how to find such D?

Comment: by scaling a disc containing $\phi(D)$ ?

Comment: @lhf I don't see how this could lead to $\phi(D)\subset D$, with the same disk $D$ on both sides.

Comment: (Link taken from the Related column on the right).